# Properties value reflects another's

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a Loan Calculator and I have 3 TextBoxes that I am trying to get to reflect one another. After I change the input of one of the TextBoxes I want the other 2 to recalculate based off the input either by pressing a calculate button that I have on my program or after the TextBox loses focus.

The three TextBoxes I've got are bound to certain values that get set upon the program being ran as well as the ability to be changed at run time:

```
     <TextBox Width="55" Height="23" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StandardTextbox}" Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:P}, Path=CurrentLoan.PropertyTaxRate, Converter={StaticResource TextBoxToDecimalConverter1}}"/>

     <TextBox Width="65" Height="23" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StandardTextbox}" Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:C}, Path=CurrentLoan.PropertyTaxMonth, Converter={StaticResource TextBoxToDecimalConverter1}}"/>

     <TextBox Width="65" Height="23" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StandardTextbox}" Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:C}, Path=CurrentLoan.PropertyTaxYear, Converter={StaticResource TextBoxToDecimalConverter1}}"/>

     CurrentLoan.PropertyTaxRate = .012;
     CurrentLoan.PropertyTaxMonth = 250;
     CurrentLoan.PropertyTaxYear = 3000;

     SharedValues.HomeValue = 250000;
```

For a home that has a value of $250,000 and has a TaxRate at 1.2%, the yearly payment is $3000 (250,000 * .012) and the monthly payment is $250 (3,000 / 12 months in a year).

Also I've got the properties already declared like so:

```
  public double PropertyTaxRate
  {
     get { return _propertyTaxRate; }
     set { SetValueAndNotify(() => PropertyTaxRate, ref _propertyTaxRate, (value > 1) ? value / 100 : value); }
  }

  public double PropertyTaxMonth
  {
     get { return _propertyTaxMonth; }
     set { SetValueAndNotify(() => PropertyTaxMonth, ref _propertyTaxMonth, value); }
  }

  public double PropertyTaxYear
  {
     get{ return _propertyTaxYear; }
     set { SetValueAndNotify(() => PropertyTaxYear, ref _propertyTaxYear, value); }
  }
```

The SetValueAndNotify method simply just sets the value to the backing property and notifies the GUI that the property has changed using INotifyPropertyChanged.

Say if I change the PropertyTaxYear property to $6,000 I want the PropertyTaxMonth to change to $500 and the PropertyTaxRate to change to 2.4%. Anyone have an Idea on how to do this and make the properties reflect one another? Thank you in advanced for your input!

Comment: Sorry. Made it more clear in the last paragraph.

Comment: Is SetAndNotify using INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry I didnt make that clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and be careful to avoid endless recursions. It helps to check `if (value != <old value>)`. Also call `SetValueAndNotify` before setting other related properties in order for this check to work.

```
public double PropertyTaxRate
{
    get { return _propertyTaxRate; }
    set { 
        if (value > 1) {
            value /= 100;
        }
        if (value != _propertyTaxRate) {
            SetValueAndNotify(() => PropertyTaxRate, ref _propertyTaxRate, value); 
            PropertyTaxYear = value * SharedValues.HomeValue;
        }
    }
}

public double PropertyTaxMonth
{
    get { return _propertyTaxMonth; }
    set {
        if (value != _propertyTaxMonth) {
            SetValueAndNotify(() => PropertyTaxMonth, ref _propertyTaxMonth, value); 
            PropertyTaxYear = 12 * value;
        }
    }
}

public double PropertyTaxYear
{
    get{ return _propertyTaxYear; }
    set { 
        if (value != _propertyTaxYear) {
            SetValueAndNotify(() => PropertyTaxYear, ref _propertyTaxYear, value);
            PropertyTaxMonth = value / 12;
            PropertyTaxRate = value / SharedValues.HomeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

The recursion problem is tougher than expected. Since `SetValueAndNotify` might trigger unexpected behaviors, I suggest to do all the calculations on the backing variables and to notify when finished. (I do not show the code of the still to create `OnNotifyPropertyChanged` method.)

```
private void Notify()
{
    OnNotifyPropertyChanged(() => PropertyTaxRate);
    OnNotifyPropertyChanged(() => PropertyTaxYear);
    OnNotifyPropertyChanged(() => PropertyTaxMonth);
}

public double PropertyTaxRate
{
    get { return _propertyTaxRate; }
    set { 
        if (value > 1) {
            value /= 100;
        }
        if (value != _propertyTaxRate) {
            _propertyTaxRate = value;
            _propertyTaxYear = value * SharedValues.HomeValue;
            _propertyTaxMonth = _propertyTaxYear / 12;
            Notify();
        }
    }
}

public double PropertyTaxMonth
{
    get { return _propertyTaxMonth; }
    set {
        if (value != _propertyTaxMonth) {
            _propertyTaxMonth = value;
            _propertyTaxYear = 12 * value;
            _propertyTaxRate =  _propertyTaxYear / SharedValues.HomeValue;
            Notify();
        }
    }
}

public double PropertyTaxYear
{
    get{ return _propertyTaxYear; }
    set { 
        if (value != _propertyTaxYear) {
            _propertyTaxYear = value;
            _propertyTaxMonth = value / 12;
            _propertyTaxRate = value / SharedValues.HomeValue;
            Notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm it's tossing an exception at me with the if statements in there. WIthout them a StackOverflow occurs. I also changed the backing properties with an added underscore

Comment: The underscores (_) were missing. (The SO answer editor is not good in selecting whole identifiers at double click.)

Comment: still a no go. Getting exceptions from that for some reason

Comment: you might as well post the exception, no?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: I added an update that eliminates recursions in a more radical way. In fact, changing one property will always change the other two, so you can notify all the properties at once.

Comment: The exception could still be an indirect result of the recursion, if the stack overflow happens during the execution of `Reflection` code.